# Breaking a file with explode

Tags: php, arrays

Today I figured out how to explode a file into fragments. I got it done with the following piece of code.

```
<?php
$file = file('url here');
foreach ($file as $files)
{
list($example) = explode(',', $file);
}
?>
```

But when I echo the $example out, I am just getting a text saying "Array" as the output. The text file which I inputted looks like the following

1,2,3,4,5

I expect the output to be like the following

1
2
3
4
5

So is it possible. If yes please help me out

Comment: This calls for basic debugging first. Please do a `error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the very beginning of your script. Additionally you should [enable error logging](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-howto-turn-on-error-log-file.html) and follow the error log.

Answer (score 3):

That is because `$example` is an array. That is why "Array" is returned. Print it like this instead:

```
foreach($example as $item) echo $item,"\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `<br>` after each item for HTML or `PHP_EOL` for text files

```
foreach ($example as $item)
{
    echo "$item<br>".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: He's not even displaying each item, he's just printing the array itself. Iteration is needed, or `implode` with `"<br/>"` (or `"\n"`, depending on where he's displaying to).

Answer (score 0):

`$example` will be an array, so you need to use `print_r()` or specify a index to echo:

```
echo $example[1];
```

Ideally, to print all the elements, you could simply do another loop:

```
foreach($example as $element){echo $element."<br>";}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have got two issues here, and you should solve one after the other. This is one I could spot:

Instead of:

```
list($example) = explode(',', $file);
```

Try with:

```
$example = explode(',', $file);
```

Also take care, that if you have multiple lines, you'll overwrite `$example`, so you might want to output it inside the `foreach` loop already.